# which Linux iSCSI target support SCSI 3 Persistant reservations?

Tags: linux, storage, storage-area-network, network-attached-storage, iscsi

looking for Linux iSCSI target software that support SCSI-3 persistent reservations?

isci enterprise target

tgt: scsi-target-utils

open-iscsi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one you need to start looking for is [linux-iscsi](http://www.linux-iscsi.org/wiki/Main_Page). It's replacing the kernel iscsi target modules as of 2.6.38 (not yet released, but soon, [git](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/nab/lio-core-2.6.git;a=tree;f=drivers/target;hb=HEAD)). It does support SCSI-3 persistant reservations, I'm using it right now on OpenSUSE 11.3 with a Microsoft Failover Cluster consuming storage via iSCSI.

Comment: wonderful and exciting !

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://scst.sourceforge.net/comparison.html) comparison chart from the SCST project includes information about which projects support persistent reservations.

Additionally, the following mailing list thread may be of interest:

- http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-stgt/msg02144.html

This is my post to the linux-stgt (aka tgt) project mailing list, which includes some examples of using the sg3-utils package to test SCSI reservations.  At the time of this post, the tgt project had support for persistent reservations, but did *not* support the `PR_OUT_PREEMPT_AND_ABORT` service action necessary to support RHEL5 i/o fencing.

Answer (score 4):

FreeNAS iSCSI targets support SCSI-3 Persistent Reservations.  I built a two node Windows Server 2008 R2 cluster running Hyper-V role and was able to Live Migrate a VM from one host/node to the other.

Answer (score -2):

SCST supports SCSI 3 persistent reservations.

Comment: Hi, for the content I suggest to ask on meta(https://meta.serverfault.com/) to have a clear idea why. It would be easier to talk than via moderator's flags. Thanks